# Does opencv have Savitzky Golay or Polynomial fit?

Tags: c++, opencv, curve-fitting, polynomials

I can't find anything similar to Savitzky Golay Polynomial Fit on opencv. This is a standard smoothing operation though, so it seems like something they should have. Does anybody know of anything they have? Using C++ for what its worth.

Thanks!
-Tim

Comment: afaik, there is no curve-fitting at all in opencv

Comment: Too bad =/ I am using another third party one right now, would be nice if they had one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you need to do: fit or smooth, you mentioned both. But if you need to smooth using OpenCV you can try [Kalman filter](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/01/kalman-filter-implementation-tracking.html) (fit in its way and smooth), [smooth-2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#smooth) (using your 1D-data) or [your own convolution smooth kernel 1D+1D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sepfilter2d) using 1D-data for kernelX only convolution (the fastest way to smooth).

OpenCV is near to real time image and video processing library, and it contains most common task solvers for this, where is no polynomial fitting among them yet. But if you really need fitting (not just smoothing) you can use polynomial fitting [matrix equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html) and calculate your answer by yourself in a simple way thanks to Mat objects in OpenCV which has `inv()`(inverse) and `t()`(transpose) functions.